# Redis HA setup: AOF issue with replicas

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I tested Redis standalone server with `AOF` persistence for every write operation, as I cannot afford to lose even one updated value from distributed clients.

1. In the Redis HA setup, does it make sense to use AOF along with
   Redis replication?
2. Is it possible to use Redis server replicas with synchronous
   replication?

In my env, the write throughput is not really high, i.e. I'm OK with a write request latency of even ~50-80 milliseconds.

Comment: What do you mean *The Redis HA setup with replicas and Sentinel is not working as expected*?

Answer (score 1):

> In the Redis HA setup, does it make sense to use AOF along with Redis replication?

Yes, you can use AOF along with Redis replication.

> Is it possible to use Redis server replicas with synchronous replication?

No. The replication is asynchronous. However, you can try [WAIT](https://redis.io/commands/wait) command to mitigate the problem.

**NOTE:** Flushing write to disk for every write operation might have a big performance problem. You'd better do benchmark before apply it to production.